# How to remove values from array in random fashion using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

```
var displayyears = [];
$scope.Joinyear=function(display){
    $scope.yeardisplay=display; 
    if (displayyears.indexOf(display) == -1) {
        $scope.selected_class[display] = "selected";
        displayyears.push($scope.yeardisplay);
    }
    else{
        $scope.selected_class[display] = "";
        displayyears.splice($scope.displayyears.indexOf(display),1);
    }
```

It works but not in correct fashion.Suppose If i have array like this [2008,2009,2010,2011]. Now I remove value from array in random manner(in between like 2009) means it remove value 2008 only...How to remove value from array in random fashion using Angular JS

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle and explain a little more clearly what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mistyped the `$scope` in this line:

```
displayyears.splice($scope.displayyears.indexOf(display),1);
```

Should be:

```
displayyears.splice(displayyears.indexOf(display),1);
```